# Using json_decode to acces HTTPS request makes my data disappear

Tags: php, json

I fetch JSON data from `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?email=foo@bar.com&format=json&q=Berlin";`, which returns

```json
[
  {
    "place_id": 574401,
    "licence": "Data Â© OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "node",
    "osm_id": 240109189,
    "boundingbox": [
      "52.3570365",
      "52.6770365",
      "13.2288599",
      "13.5488599"
    ],
    "lat": "52.5170365",
    "lon": "13.3888599",
    "display_name": "Berlin, 10117, Deutschland",
    "class": "place",
    "type": "city",
    "importance": 0.8975390282491362,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_place_city.p.20.png"
  },
  {
    "place_id": 256375666,
    "licence": "Data Â© OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "osm_type": "relation",
    "osm_id": 62422,
    "boundingbox": [
      "52.3382448",
      "52.6755087",
      "13.088345",
      "13.7611609"
    ],
    "lat": "52.5015217",
    "lon": "13.4025498",
    "display_name": "Berlin, Deutschland",
    "class": "boundary",
    "type": "administrative",
    "importance": 0.8975390282491362,
    "icon": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"
  }
]
```

Now I try to acces the first key's `lat` and `lon` key. For that I would convert it using `$new_resp=json_decode($response, true)` inly returns the String "Array". How can I get the first lon and lat values?

Comment: _“returns the String "Array"”_ - no, it doesn’t. That’s just what you get when _you_ force an array into a string context - like, trying to output it directly via `echo`. Use `var_dump` or `print_r` to make debug outputs of arrays or other complex objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this once.

```
    $curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?email=foo@bar.com&format=json&q=Berlin');

    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession),true);

    print_r($jsonData[0]['lat']); //This prints your first lat
    print_r($jsonData[0]['lon']); //This prints your first lon
    //if you want lat & lon for every record then use foreach loop. 

    curl_close($curlSession);
```

Comment: Works amazingly, however there is a typo in line 10: should be `['lon']`.

Comment: Edited answer for typo, Thanks!!